# Customer defined function returns error when used in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, dplyr, user-defined-functions

When I include a self defined function `dplyr` using `mutate` the function returns an error. When using the function in the console with manual input it works correctly.

I've tested this function to calculate fiscal periods with manual input via the console where it runs flawlessly. But when using it with the 'mutate' function in `dplyr` the function breaks because the 'seq' function included in my user defined function doesn't get the variables it needs. Although I've included already the print command which prints the variables from the function to the console.

```
FiscalPeriod <- function(Cal_Date,ReturnType){
  testdate <- Cal_Date
  #calculate end of FY for test date
  startdate = paste0(year(testdate),"-11-01")
  enddate = paste0(year(testdate),"-11-30")

  seq(from=as.Date(startdate),to=as.Date(enddate),
      by="days")

  nr_fri <- length(which(wday(seq(from=as.Date(startdate),to=as.Date(enddate),
                                by="days"),label=TRUE)=="Fri"))
  FY_end <- as.Date(timeNthNdayInMonth(startdate,nday=5,nth=nr_fri))

  #assign the fiscal year of the test date to var calc_fy
  calc_fy <- ifelse(as.Date(testdate)<= FY_end,year(testdate),year(testdate)+1)
  #recalc end of fiscal year, depending on calc_fy
  startdate = paste0(calc_fy,"-11-01")
  enddate = paste0(calc_fy,"-11-30")
  nr_fri <- length(which(wday(seq(from=as.Date(startdate),to=as.Date(enddate),
                                by="days"),label=TRUE)=="Fri"))
  FY_end <- as.Date(timeNthNdayInMonth(startdate,nday=5,nth=nr_fri))

  #calculate start of FY for test date
  FY_start <- as.Date(timeNthNdayInMonth(startdate,nday=5,nth=nr_fri))-363

  #now calculate weeks from start of FY
  calc_fw <- as.numeric(ceiling(difftime(testdate,FY_start,units="weeks")))

  #calculate fiscal quarter
  calc_fq <- as.numeric(ceiling(calc_fw/13))

  #calculate fiscal month
  calc_fm <- as.numeric(ceiling(calc_fw/4))

  if (ReturnType == "FQ"){
    return(paste0(calc_fy,"FQ",sprintf("%02d",calc_fq)))
  }

  if (ReturnType == "FM"){
    return(paste0(calc_fy,"FM",sprintf("%02d",calc_fm)))
  }

  if (ReturnType == "FW"){
    return(paste0(calc_fy,"FW",sprintf("%02d",calc_fw)))
  }

  #clean up temporary variables
  rm(testdate)
  rm(FY_start)
  rm(FY_end)
  rm(nr_fri)
  rm(startdate)
  rm(enddate)

}
```

Below some mock up data to test with:

```
person <- c("Sally","Peter","Joe","Anna")
birthday <- c("1981-05-12","1970-01-31","1985-11-11","1975-07-19")
testdf <-data.frame(person,birthday)

testdf %>% 
  mutate(FP = FiscalPeriod(birthday,"FW"))
```

This is the output when running the function on a data frame

```
Error in seq.Date(from = as.Date(startdate), to = as.Date(enddate), by = "days") : 
  'from' must be of length 1
Called from: seq.Date(from = as.Date(startdate), to = as.Date(enddate), by = "days")
```

It looks as if the `seq(from=...,to=...)` doesn't get any input. I've put already `print(startdate)` and `print(enddate)` in the line before, which bumps out the value of both `startdate` and `enddate` to the console.

Comment: The error can occur when either the from date is greater than the `to` date.  You can check by having some `print` statements in the function

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes thinking and rethinking helps!

Solved by grouping and ungrouping on a unique identifier

```
id <- seq(1:nrow(testdf),by=1)
testdf <- cbind(id,testdf)

testdf %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(FP = FiscalPeriod(birthday,"FW")) %>%
  ungroup
```